# Hateos response fails when mixing spring data rest with custom controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I've a spring boot application that uses both spring data rest to manipulate collections on a mongo db and custom controller. I have one controller whose state looks like it is broken when I make other data rest calls.

Here is my custom controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listDeployedServers", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resources<String>> getDeployedServerList(){

  MongoOperations mongoOps = getMongo();

  //No filter needed, query object is empty
  String collectionName = mongoOps.getCollectionName(DeploymentRecord.class);
  List<String> servers = Utils.castList(String.class, mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName).distinct("vmName",new Query().getQueryObject()));
  servers.removeAll(getNonActiveServerList());
  servers.sort(null);
  Resources<String> serverResources = new Resources<String>(servers);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(serverResources);
}
```

This controller works fine when called initially after a fresh start. Then I can call some other self generated data rest api and it continue to works fine. But if I call some search from the MongoRepository, the next call will get me an error:

```
  "exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
  "message" : "Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources[\"_embedded\"])",
  "path" : "/api/listDeployedServers"
```

My repository class is quite standard:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "deployment", path = "deployment")
public interface DeploymentRepository extends MongoRepository<DeploymentRecord, String> {

    public List<DeploymentRecord> findByVmNameOrderByDeploymentTimeDesc(@Param("vmName") String vmName);

    public List<DeploymentRecord> findByCuramVersion(@Param("curamVersion") String curamVersion);

    public DeploymentRecord findFirstByVmNameOrderByDeploymentTimeDesc(@Param("vmName") String vmName);

}
```

and all this calls continue to works fine. If I don't call any search it works fine. If I restart it, it will work fine.

The error seems to be in the way I tried to return the resources. If I debug the custom controller the `Resource<String>` object I create is totally correct. It's the return that fails.

Am I doing it in the wrong way? Shouldn't I use the `Resources<String>` but use something else? Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**
a workaround I found is to create a dummy object to contain the list, and then return a Resouce of that object instead of the Resources I was using before. This will work also after calling a search.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listDeployedServers", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<ListResource>> getDeployedServerList(){

        MongoOperations mongoOps = getMongo();

        //No filter needed, query object is empty
        String collectionName = mongoOps.getCollectionName(DeploymentRecord.class);
        List<String> servers = Utils.castList(String.class, mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName).distinct("vmName",new Query().getQueryObject()));
        servers.removeAll(getNonActiveServerList());
        servers.sort(null);
        Resource<ListResource> resource = new Resource<ListResource>(new ListResource(servers));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
    }

class ListResource {
    private List<String> list;

    public ListResource(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
    public List<String> getList() {
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

Looks like a waste of time/code though :-/

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the error? The interaction with MongoDB looks pretty sloppy. Any reason you're not using `MongoOperations` directly instead of the low level API?

Comment: The spring boot log is not very helpful as no stack trace is shown and the error message is the same (it is also managed as a warning) : 

`2018-02-27 13:07:36.972  WARN 18267 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"])`

Comment: Not sure I'm following you on the other point: I'm using `MongoOperation` on my custom controller, while on the other snippet I'm using the default interface constructors coming from spring data rest, which is totally fine for me, as I don't want to re-write them and they're working good.